# How do I translate a string to a vaild email address?

Tags: encryption, decode

I found a interesting job ad in Seek[job description](http://www.seek.com.au/job/31209327?pos=5&type=standard&engineConfig=&userqueryid=179240819305163636&tier=no_tier&whereid=3000).
The email address has been encrypted as a string "am9icytpdEB0b3VyaXNtaG9sZGluZ3MuY29t". I am curious about decoding it and how can it been decoded to a vaild email address.

Comment: This is probably a qualifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email address has been *encoded*, not *encrypted*. If it were encrypted, you'd have virtually no hope of determining the original value without more information!

This is an example of Base64 encoding. Read all about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and use online tools to decode it such as [this](https://www.base64decode.org/).

The decoded email address is:

> jobs+it@tourismholdings.com

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is a good guess because it contains upper and lower case letters and numbers, is a multiple of 4 characters in length. Trying Base64 decoding:

> jobs+it@tourismholdings.com

A good online Base64 decoder is [Base 64 Encoder/Decoder](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html) because it also handles binary output. It also supports dozens of other encodings.

Base64 encoding is **not** encryption, they are two entirely different things.